Hypergeometric functions matlab
I want to use the hypergeometric function:

this exists in Mathematica (Wolfram)...
]
...and Python docs link.
I cant find the equivalent in MATLAB, does it exist? If not is there a way to use Mathematica or Python functions in Matlab or some other workaround for this?

Update, I tried this:
function result = hypegeo(q, r)
    qr = q * r;
    z = - (qr)^2 / 4; 
    inp=[3/2,[1, 5/2],z];
    F2_value = hypergeom(1,2,inp);
    result = (1/3) * F2_value;
end

but for me looking at the definition of the hyper geometric function in MATLAB doesn't seem exactly the same as the one in Wolfram and Python.

The equation shown in the docs you link to for the Python function mpmath.hyper() is identical to that for the MATLAB function hypergeom(), and identical to that for the Mathematica function hypergeometric().

It looks to me that you should’t call the function with
inp=[3/2,[1, 5/2],z];
F2_value = hypergeom(1,2,inp);

but with
F2_value = hypergeom(3/2, [1, 5/2], z);

since a1 is 3/2, b1 is 1, and b2 is 5/2.
You were putting all these values into the z argument instead.
